# .setTimestamp not working with an embed being edited with a loop

Tags: discord.js

I have this embed:

```js
var msgArr = [];
var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Foo')
    .setDescription('Bar')
    .setTimestamp();

message.channel.send(embed).then(sentMessage => {
    msgArr.push(sentMessage);
});
```

Which is then edited:

```js
embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Bar')
    .setDescription('Foo')
    .setTimestamp();

msgArr[0].edit(embed);
```

This editing process is repeated multiple times on a loop:

```js
var counter = 0;
const frequency = 30000;
setInterval(function () {
    if (counter++ % 2 == 0) {
        embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Bar')
            .setDescription('Foo')
            .setTimestamp();
        msgArr[0].edit(embed);
    } else {
        embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Foo')
            .setDescription('Bar')
            .setTimestamp();
        msgArr[0].edit(embed);
    }
}, frequency);
```

(Basically the title and the description switch between `'Foo'` and `'Bar'` every 30 seconds, with a `.setTimestamp` included)

Now, what happens when I run this is that the `.setTimestamp` will work fine for the first minute or 2, then it starts to 'lag' behind the actual time. Can anyone help me figure out the reason for this?

Full Code (Yes there have been some parts cut out, but there are related to API things that have no effect on the embed part):

```js
// Some code is commented out due to requests you have made, it should be obvious which code this is. I haven't cleaned up the commented out code, therefore be warned there will be some variables that aren't in this.

const Discord = require('discord.js');
// Below is normally not constant
const itemAmount = 6;
module.exports = {
    name: 'command',
    cooldown: 1,
    description: 'Test Description',
    execute(message) {
        function sendEmbeds(channel1, channel2) {
            message.client.channels.cache.get(channel1).bulkDelete(8);
            for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                let now = new Date();
                let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('#141414')
                    .setTitle(i + 1 + '. Item')
                    .setDescription(now.toString())
                    //  .setDescription('This is an item you can **buy** with `Bits` and then **sell** as a `BIN` for easy Skyblock Coins \n ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━')
                    .setThumbnail('some url')
                    .addFields(
                        { name: 'Information:', value: 'Buy Price: `1500 Bits`\n Sell Price: `250000 Coins` \n Coins per Bit Spent: `250 Coins`', inline: true },
                    )
                    .setTimestamp(now)
                    .setFooter('Powered by - SKY | Brokers', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/715801930877894706/a_95042b5d9aee771fdddec12191fb6092.webp?size=128');
                // Next if statement is api related, but since it's important to the embed it'll stay
                if (itemAmount >= 5) {
                    embed.setTitle(i + 1 + '. **HARD TO SELL**: Item');
                }
                message.client.channels.cache.get(channel1).send(embed).then(sentMessage => {
                    msgArr.push(sentMessage);
                });
            }
            message.client.channels.cache.get(channel2).bulkDelete(5);
            for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                let now = new Date();
                var craftableEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('#141414')
                    .setTitle(i + 1 + '. Item')
                    .setDescription(now.toString())
                    //  .setDescription('This is an item you can craft by **buying** `' + craftables[craft[i][0]]["amountNeeded"] + ' ' + craftables[craft[i][0]]["itemNeeded"]["name"] + '` from the lowest BIN, buying `' + craftables[craft[i][0]]["bitsItem"] + '` with `Bits` and then **selling** as a `BIN` for easy Skyblock Coins \n ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━')
                    .setThumbnail('some thumbnail')
                    .addFields(
                        { name: 'Information:', value: 'Bits Buy Price: `1200 Bits` \n Item Buy Price: `500000 Coins` \n Sell Price Per Crafted Item: `600000 Coins` \n Profit Per Craft: `746889 Coins` \n Coins per Bit Spent: `153.6 Coins`', inline: true },
                    )
                    .setTimestamp(now)
                    .setFooter('Powered by - SKY | Brokers', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/715801930877894706/a_95042b5d9aee771fdddec12191fb6092.webp?size=128');
                message.client.channels.cache.get(channel2).send(craftableEmbed).then(sentMessage => {
                    msgArrCraft.push(sentMessage);
                });
            }
        }

        function editEmbeds() {
            for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                let now = new Date();
                console.log(now);
                let embedNew = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('#141414')
                    .setTitle(i + 1 + '. Item')
                    .setDescription(now.toString())
                    //  .setDescription('This is an item you can **buy** with `Bits` and then **sell** as a `BIN` for easy Skyblock Coins \n ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━')
                    .setThumbnail('some thumbnail')
                    .addFields(
                        { name: 'Information:', value: 'Buy Price: `1500 Bits`\n Sell Price: `250000 Coins` \n Coins per Bit Spent: `250 Coins`', inline: true },
                    )
                    .setTimestamp(now)
                    .setFooter('Powered by - SKY | Brokers', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/715801930877894706/a_95042b5d9aee771fdddec12191fb6092.webp?size=128');
                if (itemAmount >= 5) {
                    embedNew.setTitle(i + 1 + '. **HARD TO SELL**: Item');
                }
                msgArr[i].edit(embedNew).then(newEmbed => {
                    msgArr[i] = newEmbed;
                    console.log(now, 'edited');
                });
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                let now = new Date();
                console.log(now);
                let craftableEmbedNew = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('#141414')
                    .setTitle(i + 1 + '. Item')
                    .setDescription(now.toString())
                    //  .setDescription('This is an item you can craft by **buying** `' + craftable[craft[i][0]]["amountNeeded"] + ' ' + craftable[craft[i][0]]["itemNeeded"]["name"] + '` from the lowest BIN, buying `' + craftable[craft[i][0]]["bitsItem"] + '` with `Bits` and then **selling** as a `BIN` for easy Skyblock Coins \n ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━')
                    .setThumbnail('some thumbnail')
                    .addFields(
                        { name: 'Information:', value: 'Bits Buy Price: `1200 Bits` \n Item Buy Price: `500000 Coins` \n Sell Price Per Crafted Item: `600000 Coins` \n Profit Per Craft: `746889 Coins` \n Coins per Bit Spent: `153.6 Coins`', inline: true },
                    )
                    .setTimestamp(now)
                    .setFooter('Powered by - SKY | Brokers', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/715801930877894706/a_95042b5d9aee771fdddec12191fb6092.webp?size=128');
                msgArrCraft[i].edit(craftableEmbedNew).then(newEmbed => {
                    msgArr[i] = newEmbed;
                    console.log(now, 'edited');
                });
            }
        }

        var msgArr = [];
        var msgArrCraft = [];
        setTimeout(() => {
            // Embed
            // The bot uses 2 channels, if you are testing this be warned that it is coded to delete 8 messages in the first channel, and 5 messages in the second. (Replace the channel IDs with the ones you are testing in)
            sendEmbeds('ChannelID1', 'ChannelID2');
        }, 15000);

        var counter = 0;
        const frequency = 30000;
        setInterval(function () {
            // Normally this if statement has API related code, this is omitted here therefore it seems useless.
            if (counter++ % 2 == 0) {
                editEmbeds();
            }
            else {
                editEmbeds();
            }
        }, frequency);
    },
};
```

If you would like the COMPLETE full code (included a ton of API related things) feel free to ask.

Comment: How much time did it lag?

Comment: Also, you use both `newEmbed` and `embedNew` in your code. Is that intended?

Comment: @sup39 After the first 1-2 minutes it starts to lag to about 5 minutes behind, after 10 minutes it starts to get to 15 minutes behind, and after 20 minutes the time almost freezes, where it goes up by one minute after about an hour. For the `newEmbed` versus `embedNew` that was just bc I wasn't thinking straight when making the example code above. In my actual project it's the same variable so it's simpler to understand.

Comment: I have edited the code to fix this error.

Comment: Can you try explicitly assigning a timestamp to `.setTimestamp`? Like: `const now = new Date();` `.setTimestamp(now);` (Also you can use `console.log(now)` to check if the timestamp of `embed` is correctly set to `now`)

Comment: @sup39 I tried that solution, and I found that it was logging the correct time to console, but the embeds would still lag behind.

Comment: That's so strange... Can you try `.setDescription(now.toString())` and comparing the description and the timestamp?

Comment: Or can you try updating `msgArr[0]` to the new `embed` after `msgArr[0].edit(embed)`, and use the new embed to `.edit` (instead of the first sent embed)? (Sorry for poor explanation) For example, changing `msgArr[0].edit(embed);` to `msgArr[0].edit(embed).then(newEmbed => {msgArr[0] = newEmbed;});`

Comment: @sup39 so I tried what you recommended and compared the description to the `.setTimestamp(now)` and surprisingly, the description was accurate with the `.setTimestamp`, yet both of them were inaccurate to the actual time. I've also noticed that the embeds seem to be 'jumpy' and it looks like they are being edited almost every 10 seconds, even though they should be editing every 30.

Comment: Does `console.log(now)` print (in console) and `embed` update (in discord) simultaneously? You may also need to log after `.edit` is done: `msgArr[0].edit(embed).then(newEmbed => {msgArr[0] = newEmbed; console.log(now, 'edited');});`

Comment: @sup39 I did what you recommended to do, and yes it does log at the same time. What I've found though is that the time it logs is actually not the time being set in the embed. But, I get 3-4 DIFFERENT times being logged. There's the accurate time being logged, then there's the time being edited (the incorrect time). This is the oddest thing I've ever seen.

Comment: I tested it and it worked well... Can you provide the whole code?

Comment: @sup39 I will provide the whole code, though I will make some modifications due to the project using an API to collect data. The only modifications that will be made will be to hard code specific values into variables that would originally be getting API data and removing all aspects of the code related to achieving this data.

Comment: In channel2, the embed updates correctly. But in channel1, the embed only update once and the timestamp stops changing. Is this same as what happened to you?

Comment: @sup39 That actually isn't what is happening to me. For me, they are both at the exact same time, which is incorrect. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: The bug I encountered was caused by a typo: `msgArrCraft[i].edit(craftableEmbedNew).then(newEmbed => {msgArr[i] = newEmbed;` should be `msgArrCraft[i].edit(craftableEmbedNew).then(newEmbed => {msgArrCraft[i] = newEmbed;` After fixing it, it worked well on my environment.

Comment: Can you post some screenshot to show what is the problem?

Comment: @sup39 So, I input the command at 12:01 AM (I'll be using EST btw)
The bot sends the embeds in the first channel, and they stop updating at about 12:05 https://gyazo.com/444919e8b1020438047aae2029ae7c3f
The bot also sends the embeds to the second channel, which seem to still be updating, just lagging behind https://gyazo.com/4eb7941d426a28a1084a4ad8defe9b58

(All pictures were taken at 12:14)

Comment: If you are willing to provide a more private method of messaging you, I'll be happy to send over all the bot files, I'd just like to keep certain parts of it private, which is why I'm not sending all the bot files here.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't provide a more private contact method... Maybe you can try to simplify the code (e.g. removing some API code) until the code works. (At least the code you provided should work) And then add them back part by part until it starts to have some problems. (Then the added part may be causing some problems) Hope you can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @sup39 I'm currently testing out what you recommended to do with slowly adding the API functions of the code, but then I remembered a difference in the example code compared to my actual code, which is that in my actual code it's updating 13 embeds all at the same time. Could that be causing the issue?

Comment: Any small change can cause the bug. It will be great to test it if you doubt it.

Comment: @sup39 I have fixed the issue, but the solution is incredibly interesting on how it worked. I made a new file and followed what you recommended of starting with just the embeds, then adding API data slowly. I do that and by the time all the API code was in it was still working fine and the time was displaying correctly. I copy all the 'edited' (literally just the same code in the same order) into the original file, ran it, and it worked exactly how I wanted it to. So basically, the solution to the problem was copying everything onto another file and pasting it into the original.

Comment: Glad that you fixed it! Sometimes it's just very small piece of the code causes the bug, which is very difficult to figure out. But after reconstructing the code part by part, the code causing the bug will probably disappear. And I believe that the original code and the fixed code must be silently different even you just copied codes to the new file and copied them back. That's how I debug if I can't easily figure out the problem. Glad that it also worked for you.